# T-SQL Insert number with leading zero into table

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I need to insert into my table a number `0000128`, but it see this number as `128`, I was trying also change type from `int` to `varchar`, but there wasn't a difference.

Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing as `varchar` should work fine.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
  V VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES      ('0000128');

SELECT *
FROM   @T
```

You must be casting to numeric along the way and losing the leading zeroes.

Comment: That's the problem, I can't loosing this zeros because it's number assigned by company, and sometimes it'll be 4 zeros, and the other time two so I need to save it, that I may recover it later. And like I said earlier, I tried with varchar and it doesn't work

Comment: @Maggie So just make sure it is treated as a string throughout. Then `000012` and `0012` won't end up as `12`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a number with a leading zero, only *textual representations of numbers* with leading zeroes.

Comment: PIN **number** and telephone **number** both are examples of things that in common parlance are called "numbers" but have significant leading zeroes though. I don't see this is a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue before when doing ETL. This is how I solved it.

```
-- declare and assign
-- this could be from anywhere
declare @int_NUMBER int = 128

-- show the original
select @int_NUMBER

-- steps:
-- first: cast the number as a varchar

-- second: create a string of zeros. The number of zeros should be equal to the max size of this "number". 
-- In this example, the max size this "number" is 7 places.

-- third: concat the leading zeros in front of the varchar of the number

-- forth: take the number of max places from the right
-- this way you will always get the proper amount of leading zeros

select right('0000000' + cast(@int_NUMBER as varchar(10)),7)
```

Results:

---

128

(1 row(s) affected)

---

0000128

(1 row(s) affected)